# Как заполнить лэйблом всю ячейку?

Tags: html, css

Как можно заполнить лэйблом всё пространство ячейки таблицы?

Я использую лэйбл как кнопку. Скрипт по нажатию на лэйбл выполняет некое действие, но, [как видите](https://tools.wmflabs.org/iluvatarbot/test.php) (зелёная галочка), если кликнуть у нижней границы ячейки, действия не происходит.

Таблица из бутстрапа. Ячейка:

```
.t_end {
   max-width: 50px;
   min-width: 50px;
   padding-right: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0px;
}
```

и находящийся в ячейке лэйбл:

```
.t_btn { 
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100% ширина и высота не поможет, даже если убрать паддинг. Если Вам так уж нужно растянуть лейбл, то может использовать комбинацию из position relative/absolute

```css
.t_btn {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 36px;/* выровнять иконку*/
}
.t_end {
  position: relative;
}
```

Обратите внимание что теперь лейбл выпадает из потока, и вам нужно гарантировано иметь контент в соседних ячейках (чтобы ячейки растягивались по высоте)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы растянуть тег `<a>` на всю ячейку, можно использовать

```
td a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Код взят отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/19326453/6131611

*Edit:* как видно на скриншоте, `<td>` имеет padding 8 пикселей.
[image]
Поэтому `<label>` не может занять всю ячейку. Чтобы исправить это, можно убрать padding у td и добавить у label. Или ловить click не на label, а на td.

Comment: Так ведь у меня именно так. В лэйбле указана 100%-ная высота и блок.